# Milvus, similarity search by cosine

Tags: milvus

How to apply cosine similarity calculation in Milvus when search for Float Vectors, without normalizing the vectors in-place ?

Comment: For now, up to milvus 2.2, this is still not supported, you need to normalize it, and then use IP distance. What is the reason you could not do a normalization for it?

Comment: Nowadays, it seems to be supported - according to the documentation. But I don't get it working on my machine